# read xml file in R, issue with foreign characters despite "correct" encoding

Tags: r, xml, encoding

I'm trying to read the following XML file: https://weburn.kb.se/riks/tv%C3%A5kammarriksdagen/xml/1867/web_mot_1867__fk__1/mot_1867__fk__1.xml.

As is stated in the beginning of the file, the encoding is `UTF-8`, i.e. on the very first line it says

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

However, it is stated that the formatting language is Swedish. There are elements in the document looking like this:

```
<line baseline="2235" l="327" t="2198" r="1763" b="2247"><formatting lang="Swedish">Den, som blifvit utsedd att vara ledamot i sådan nämnd, som omförmäles</formatting></line>
```

So when I read the file using the following code:

```
library(httr)
UA <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.0 Safari/537.36"

my_url <- "https://weburn.kb.se/riks/tv%C3%A5kammarriksdagen/xml/1867/web_mot_1867__fk__1/mot_1867__fk__1.xml"
my_doc <- GET(my_url, user_agent(UA))

res <- xmlParse(content(my_doc, "text", encoding = "UTF-8"))
```

the corresponding output (For that particular part) becomes

```
<line baseline="2235" l="327" t="2198" r="1763" b="2247">
            <formatting lang="Swedish">Den, som blifvit utsedd att vara ledamot i sÃ¥dan nÃ¤mnd, som omfÃ¶rmÃ¤les</formatting>
          </line>
```

How can I get the right encoding with å, ä, ö?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this encoding issue. What OS are you using? Also please make sure the variable names are correct in your example. You don't define `UA` and you switch from `doc` to `my_doc`. Are you sure you are using the correct values in your own code?

Comment: Fixed the code. sorry about that. I'm using windows.

Comment: Check  `Sys.getlocale()`; apply `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", ".65001")` or `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", ".utf8")` if necessary. Should work in *R version 4.2.0*. BTW, *could not find function "xmlParse"*…